# App crashes due to The operation couldn't be completed. (KCLErrorDomain error 1.)

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit, core-location

I have a problem with an app.
I wrote it last week and it worked on both the simulator and my iPhone.
Now I wanted to make a few small changes today, but every time I try to simulate them, I get the error:

**In the simulator:
"The operation couldn't be completed. (KCLErrorDomain error 1.)"
On my iPhone:
"QUARANTINED DUE TO HIGH LOGGING VOLUME"**

although I haven't changed anything in the code and always ask the user for permission whether the app is allowed to use the location.
Whenever I start the app, my location is shown in the window in which I am asked for permission and if I then click on "Only use once", I no longer see my location and the app does not react to gestures etc.

Here is my code, it would be great if someone had an idea what the problem is, since I've googled a lot and tried, but somehow nothing seems to work.

p.s.: sorry for no commentary :X

**MapViewModel**:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


var region1 = CLCircularRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.503117, longitude: 13.348901), radius: 20, identifier: "region1")
var region2 = CLCircularRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.504829, longitude: 13.336798), radius: 20, identifier: "region2")
var region3 = CLCircularRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.504733, longitude: 13.341834), radius: 20, identifier: "region3")
var region4 = CLCircularRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.503312, longitude: 13.347718), radius: 20, identifier: "region4")
var region5 = CLCircularRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.505699, longitude: 13.352198), radius: 20, identifier: "region5")
var region6 = CLCircularRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.513517, longitude: 13.350253), radius: 20, identifier: "region6")


class MapViewModel : NSObject,ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{
    
    @Published var mapView = MKMapView()
    @Published var region : MKCoordinateRegion!
    @Published var permissionDenied = false
    @Published var alerts = Array(repeating: false, count: 7)
    @Published var mapType : MKMapType = .standard
    @Published var searchTxt = ""
    @Published var places : [Place] = []
    @Published var currentPin: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    @Published var currentmap = CGPoint()
    @Published var UserDidZoom: Bool = false;
    
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var Waypoints = [region1, region2, region3, region4, region5, region6];
    var Pins: [MKPointAnnotation] = []
    @Published var RegionIndex: Int = 6
    private var mapChangedFromUserInteraction = false
    
    
    func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
        let view = mapView.subviews[0]
        if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
            for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
                if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended ) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        mapChangedFromUserInteraction = mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction()

    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
            UserDidZoom = true
            mapView.userTrackingMode = .none
        }
    }
    

    func updateMapType(){
        
        if mapType == .standard{
            mapType = .hybrid
            mapView.mapType = mapType
        }else{
            mapType = .standard
            mapView.mapType = mapType
        }
    }
    
    func focusLocation() {
        let rangeInMeters: Double = 500
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: region.center, latitudinalMeters: rangeInMeters,longitudinalMeters: rangeInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
    
    func searchQuery(){
        
        places.removeAll()
        
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchTxt
        
        MKLocalSearch(request: request).start { (response, _) in
            guard let result = response else{return}
            
            self.places = result.mapItems.compactMap({ (item) -> Place? in
                return Place(placemark: item.placemark)
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    func selectPlace(place: Place){
        
        searchTxt = ""
        guard let coordinate = place.placemark.location?.coordinate else{return}
        
        let pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
        pointAnnotation.title = place.placemark.name ?? "No Name"
        
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        
        mapView.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
        
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapView.visibleMapRect, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        
        switch manager.authorizationStatus{
        case .denied:
            permissionDenied.toggle()
        case .notDetermined:
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            manager.requestLocation()
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else{return}
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
        
        if(!UserDidZoom){
            
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
        self.isWayPoint()
    }
    func initPositionService(){
        
        let startPointRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.506016, longitude: 13.33206), latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
        mapView.setRegion(startPointRegion, animated: true)
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.delegate = self
        
        
    }
    
    func placeAnnotations(){
        
        let toDoLocation = ["Friseur: Haare schneiden " , "Dönerbude: zu Mittag essen" , "Bank: Geld abheben" ,  "Supermarkt: einkaufen" ,  "Blumeneladen: Blumen kaufen" ,  "Lisa's Wohnung: Lisa Blumen überreichen"]
        
        
        for i  in 0...5 {
            
            let point = MKPointAnnotation()
            
            point.coordinate = Waypoints[i].center
            point.title = toDoLocation[i]
            
            Pins.append(point)
        }
        mapView.addAnnotations(Pins)
    
        
        
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        
        if(region.identifier == "region1"){
            self.RegionIndex = 0
        }else if(region.identifier == "region2"){
            self.RegionIndex = 1
        }else if(region.identifier == "region3"){
            self.RegionIndex = 2
        }else if(region.identifier == "region4"){
            self.RegionIndex = 3
        }else if(region.identifier == "region5"){
            self.RegionIndex = 4
        }else if(region.identifier == "region6"){
            self.RegionIndex = 5
        }
    }
    
    func isWayPoint() {
        
        while(self.Waypoints.count > 0){
        
            for i in self.Waypoints {
                self.manager.startMonitoring(for: i)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**MapView**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import Combine

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var  mapData: MapViewModel
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return MapView.Coordinator()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        
        let view = mapData.mapView
        view.showsUserLocation = true
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate{
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            
            if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self){return nil}
            else{
                
                let pinAnnotation = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "PIN_VIEW")
                pinAnnotation.tintColor = .blue
                pinAnnotation.animatesDrop = true
                pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = true
               
                return pinAnnotation
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
 }
```

**Place**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Place: Identifiable{
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var placemark: CLPlacemark
 
}
```

**ContentView**

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import AVFoundation


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var mapData = MapViewModel()
    @State var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1015
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            MapView()
                .environmentObject(mapData)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            
            VStack{
                
                VStack(spacing : 0){
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        TextField("Search", text: $mapData.searchTxt)
                            .colorScheme(.light)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    
                    if !mapData.places.isEmpty && mapData.searchTxt != ""{
                        
                        ScrollView{
                            VStack(spacing:10){
                                ForEach(mapData.places){place in
                                    
                                    Text(place.placemark.name ?? "")
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding(.leading)
                                        .onTapGesture{
                                            mapData.selectPlace(place: place)
                                        }
                                    Divider()
                                 }
                             }
                            .padding(.top)
                         }
                        .background(Color.white)
                     }
                 }
                .padding()
                
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    
                    Button(action:{ mapData.focusLocation(); mapData.UserDidZoom = false; mapData.mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow  },label:{
                        
                        Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(Color.primary)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    })
                    .opacity(mapData.UserDidZoom ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    
                    Button(action: mapData.updateMapType ,label:{
                        
                        Image(systemName: mapData.mapType == .standard ? "network" : "map")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(Color.primary)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    })
                 }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
           
            mapData.initPositionService()
            mapData.placeAnnotations()
            
            
        })
        .onChange(of: mapData.RegionIndex) { regionIndex in
            var done = Array(repeating: false, count: 7)
            if( regionIndex <= 5 ){
                if(done[regionIndex] == false){
                    mapData.currentPin = mapData.Pins[regionIndex]
                    mapData.alerts[regionIndex] = true
                    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(systemSoundID)
                    mapData.mapView.removeAnnotation(mapData.currentPin)
                    done[regionIndex] = true
                }
            }
         }
        .alert(isPresented: $mapData.alerts[mapData.RegionIndex], content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Ziel erreicht"), message: Text("Sie haben \(mapData.currentPin.title!) erledigt"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok"), action: {mapData.alerts[mapData.RegionIndex] = false} ))
        })
        .onChange(of: mapData.searchTxt, perform: { value in
            
            let delay = 0.3
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay){
                
                if value == mapData.searchTxt{
                    self.mapData.searchQuery()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: KCLErrorDomain error 1 occurs when the user denies location services. Can you add comments to your code about what you changed and why? This is where source control is your friend.